# Prove that there doesn't exist prime numbers $a, b, c$ s.t. $a^2=b^2+c^3$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I first showed that if $a,b,c \neq$ 2, then they are odd and therefore are never equal. Then I consider the cases where $a=2$, $b=2$ and $c=2$.

It seems to be unnecessarily long so is there a more concise proof?

(I have a strong filling that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic could be applied here, but I couldn't figure out how.)

Comment: The key is to factor the right hand side of $c^3 = a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Just a sketch of the proof: if
$$ p^3 = (a-b)(a+b) $$
then $(a-b)$ and $(a+b)$ are two divisors of $p^3$ with the same parity, such that $(a-b)\leq (a+b)$.

For instance, if $p$ is odd, $a-b=1$ and $a+b=p^3$, then $a=\frac{p^3+1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{p^3-1}{2}$. However, in such a case neither $a$ or $b$ is a prime, since $a=\frac{p+1}{2}\cdot(p^2-p+1)$ and $b=\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot (p^2+p+1)$.